# how voip services call multiple telephone lines at same time

Tags: voip

I recently see a voip dialer for mobile which we can purchase a username and password. And make calls to telephones. I think thousands of people are using this service. My question is how they call to phones from the voip server? Will they take 1000+ telephone lines for calling out ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my limited knowledge, VOIP or voice over internet protocol works similar to a normal telephone network, using switching networks. There is probably some interface between internet and a telephone network at some point, from where the call is routed through a normal telephone exchange which sends the call to the desired receiver using switches.

BTW this is more of a question on Networking than Programming! You can try posting it on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/